# Is this a design pattern and does it have a common name?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a library with only interfaces and basic objects, lets call it API. The API has a few known implementations, that may increase in number for the needs of an application. The application can use only one implementation at a time. I have another library, lets call it PROXY, which provides a basic implementation of the API library, and it delegates the logic to a real implementation of the API. The real implementation is provided by configuration and the PROXY library takes care of creating the appropriate real classes and wrapping them. The idea is to use the API and PROXY libraries in my code, so that I can change implementations without recompiling the application - just changing the configuration and providing the real implementation library in the classpath. Here is an example code in C#:

API:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

PROXY:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private IFoo _realFoo;

    public Foo()
    {
        _realFoo = ...; // Assume reading the config and creating the real implementation with reflection here.
    }

    void Bar()
    {
        _realFoo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Real Implementation:

```
public class RealFoo : IFoo
{
    void Bar()
    {
        // Some specific logic 
    }
}
```

I guess the Foo class above uses `Decorator Pattern` to wrap arround the real implementation. I am more interested if the whole approach has a specific name?

Comment: Whats there in the name?

Comment: This will help me give some sensible name for the library I will write that I call PROXY here, and will help me explain my idea better.

Comment: You can also name it according to the usage. If the PROXY is created to testing, you can call it a test double or fake implementation.

Comment: My intention is to use it in a project in production as part of an update. I cannot afford to use DI and other stuff as the project deployed and approved by the client, and is not designed to use DI. I need easier maintainability for some components, so I intent to use the approach described here. Each time a component is updated, I only replace the component library and change the config, without redeploying the entire application. Fortunately it is possible to isolate the API without much effort and it is a potential investment for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a use of the Decorator pattern for a number of reasons, most importantly in intent.

It is a Proxy.  Genericly the proxy pattern

> Provides a surrogate or placeholder for another object to control
>   access to it

The fact that you are using it to dynamically load your implementation and therefore have a loose coupling with your implementation based on configuration also make it similar to Dependency Injection.  Your version differs in that you have a proxy object in the middle.  If instead your client held a reference to RealFoo, but this reference was obtained via the kind of mechanisms you are talking about, then that would more closely match Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thanks, it seem I've not been mistaken by naming it `proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

I use IoC/DI for exactly the same thing and Castle Windsor as my IoC container.

http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: Yes, it is some sort of `Inversion of Control`, a but more cumbersome and less flexible than the DI. Still it tickles me from inside how do I name it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have mixed Proxy pattern with some kind of Factory Method Pattern.

In plain proxy pattern, the proxy object does not create the main target itself. But instead some Factory class which is supposed to create objects of target type, creates the target instance and passes it to a proxy instance and finally returns the proxy.

There are also different ways to create proxy objects. take a look to Castle Dynamic Proxy for instance, -- That is intended to provide ASPECTS.

Comment: Yep, I might have mixed the patterns you mention. I could not however use plain DI, see my last comment on the question, so I took the approach I described.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you looking for the name of the patterns or you are looking for a solution to a particular problem?

Comment: Primarily for the name of it. I already used it successfully as a solution to my case, but it bothers me a bit because I called it `proxy`. It is no urgent issue anyway.

Comment: I disagree with "In plain proxy pattern, the proxy object does not create the main target itself".  This usage is one of the implementation examples listed in the Proxy section in 'Design Patterns' by the GoF.